# Contact_Remover class isn't "catching" my contacts in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-contacts

For some reason, my `Remove_Contacts` activity, mainly called `Main_Remove_Contacts`, which *should (at least I think)* automatically link to the contacts the phone has, is not, and instead shows no contacts whatsoever.

This tutorial I watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uS7cVb9WBNA shows that when adding contacts, it should spontaneously add them to this list. My `Add_Contacts` activity works correctly, after refreshing, but not this one...

Here's some pictures and the code for each:

[image: Menu]

[image: Remove_Contacts]

Even after refreshing, nothing shows up. And I have tested the "Add Contact" one, it works, as you can see by the last tests I added.

Code for:

- Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MainAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        checkPermission();
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this
                , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 100);
        }else{
            getContactList();
        }

        Button add_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

        add_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_Contact.class)));

        Button rem_btn = findViewById(R.id.rem_btn);

        rem_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Remove_Contact.class)));
    }

    private void getContactList() {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String sort = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                uri, null, null, null, sort
        );

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                ));
                Uri uriPhone = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                        + " =?";
                Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        uriPhone, null, selection,
                        new String[]{id}, null
                );
                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                    String number = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    ));
                    ContactModel model = new ContactModel();
                    model.setName(name);
                    model.setNumber(number);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MainAdapter(this,arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getContactList();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checkPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

- Add Contact:

```
public class Add_Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText phone;
    Button addContact;

    @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);

        name = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        addContact = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        addContact.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (!name.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !email.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone.getText().toString());
                    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Contact.this, "There is no app that supports this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Contact.this, "Please fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

- Remove Contact (Main):

```
public class Main_Remove_Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listView;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    int PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS = 1000;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                showContacts();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_check:
                for(int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
                    listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                deleteContacts();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void deleteContacts() {
        Cursor phones = null;
        SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
            if(checked.valueAt(i) == true){
                phones = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(i);
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Remove_Contact.deleteContact(getContentResolver(), phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        phones.close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact(s) deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remove_contact);
        initView();

        if((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
            },PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS);
        }else{
            showContacts();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_READ_WRITE_CONTACTS){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                showContacts();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot display your contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showContacts() {
        Cursor cursor = Remove_Contact.getContactCursor(getContentResolver(),"");
        String[] fields = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, fields, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void initView() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Contact Remover");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

- Remove Contact:

```
    public static Cursor getContactCursor(ContentResolver contactHelper, String startsWith){
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor cur = null;
        try{
            if(startsWith != null && !startsWith.equals("")){
                cur = contactHelper.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " line \""
                        + startsWith + "%\"",null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " ASC");
            }else{
                cur = contactHelper.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,null,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
            }
            cur.moveToFirst();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cur;
    }

    public static void deleteContact(ContentResolver contactHelper, String number){
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(getContactID(contactHelper,number))};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID+"=?",args).build());
        try{
            contactHelper.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,ops);
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (OperationApplicationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static long getContactID(ContentResolver contactHelper, String number) {
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
        Cursor cur = null;
        try{
            cur = contactHelper.query(contactUri,projection,null,null,null);
            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                int personID = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID);
                return cur.getLong(personID);
            }
            return -1;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(cur != null){
                cur.close();
                cur = null;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Any clue on why the connection is not getting linked? The only reason I showed the "Add Contact" activity is because maybe there's a connection that isn't in the "Remove Contact" one. I'm not sure exactly.